# foreach inside foreach gets wrong value

Tags: laravel, foreach, nested

I want the output to be like this
[image]

but am getting like this
[image]

The problem is 4th row doesn't have a value but the value is showing in that..

My code looks like this

```
 @if($fridges)
  @foreach($fridges as $index => $fridge)
    @foreach($fridgereadings as $index1 => $fridgereading)
       @if($fridge->fridge_no == $fridgereading->fridge_id)
           @php $morning_reading = $fridgereading->morning_reading; @endphp
       @endif
    @endforeach
    <tr>
         <td>{{ $fridge->fridge_no }}</td>
              <input id="fridge_id" name="fridge_id[]" value="{{ $fridge->fridge_no }}" type="hidden" class="form-control">
         <td><input value="@if(!empty($morning_reading)) {{ $morning_reading }} @endif" id="morning_reading" name="morning_reading[]" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
         <td><input id="evening_reading" name="evening_reading[]" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

The fourth row `Fridge No` doesn't have a value in the `Morning reading` Column but it's showing how can we prevent that..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to destroy variables defined in loop after each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336118/how-to-destroy-variables-defined-in-loop-after-each-iteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not resetting the value of `$morning_reading` on each pass through the loop, so when you process fridge 4 and find no value for it in `$fridgereadings`, `$morning_reading` retains its previous value (in this case, `30`). You need to assign a default value in case there is no reading:

```php
 @if($fridges)
  @foreach($fridges as $index => $fridge)
    @php $morning_reading = ''; @endphp
    @foreach($fridgereadings as $index1 => $fridgereading)
       @if($fridge->fridge_no == $fridgereading->fridge_id)
           @php $morning_reading = $fridgereading->morning_reading; @endphp
       @endif
    @endforeach
    <tr>
         <td>{{ $fridge->fridge_no }}</td>
              <input id="fridge_id" name="fridge_id[]" value="{{ $fridge->fridge_no }}" type="hidden" class="form-control">
         <td><input value="@if(!empty($morning_reading)) {{ $morning_reading }} @endif" id="morning_reading" name="morning_reading[]" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
         <td><input id="evening_reading" name="evening_reading[]" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
@endif
```